# Where can I find pre-painted minatures for D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, miniatures

I have started playing sanctioned AL play at my local game store weekly. Until now, my experience has been purely online through VTT's and my first experience was amazing. Only...I had no token for my character and had to effectively borrow one that session, which the DM was able to supply me.

I have gone on a search in 2 of my local game stores and came up with white miniatures being put out on WotC behalf that want to be painted. Hero Forge custom 3D prints mini's .... that again want to be painted.

Question: Can I find or custom order a character miniature that is already colored?

I have no painting skills to speak of, let alone for that kind of precision, and I will have this character for a very long time through levels 1-20 sanctioned play. A token would be worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. They do exist, and can easily be found online with a bit of searching:

- https://www.trollandtoad.com/
- https://www.miniaturemarket.com/
- http://beholderthebargains.com/
- http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/miniatures
- https://www.coolstuffinc.com/page/1315

Answer (score 3):

A good option is to try and find hobby stores that sell second hand miniatures. There will be a chance that you can find ones that have already been painted. Alternatively online sites might have painted miniatures for sale from individuals.

Another option is to buy your miniature as is and then hire someone to paint it professionally for you.

I avoided citing specifics as I am unsure on the rules regarding this type of question

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all well and true, but here are a two more options:

### Micheals

The craft store carries some generic fantasy creatures and charactors that are colored (not sure if it is paint, per se).  They are cheaper than a lot of painted mini options. Its not bad for a monster or two, or a wizard, but the options are limited.  Some of them are odd scales, but depending on what you're looking for...

### Lego

Lego minifigs are oddly proportioned, but they are a nice size for a 1 inch grid/hex and the height isn't too different from a standard mini.  It also allows customizations of clothing and gear.